# Thunderbird crashed after installing Lightning

Tags: thunderbird, calendar

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and have decided to start using Thunderbird. It worked well, only complaint that it kept on asking me for the master password for every account that I have every time I opened. No big deal. Then I decided to add lightning so that I can see my calendar. It loaded up the calendar no problem, BUT then it asks me for my password, and after I give it, Thunderbird shuts down. I can't uninstall the lightning plug-in, as I can't open Thunderbird....

Anybody have any ideas?

I have purged Thunderbird, but when I reinstall it, it seems to have stored my info somewhere, because exactly the same thing happens...

Answer (score 0):

### 1. "reset" thunderbird by moving your profile

`mv ~./.thunderbird/$yourId /tmp/`.

Restart thunderbird.

### 2. Lighning

I've experienced the same issue with Lightning. My TB version 45.5.1.  <s>Me helped the installation of the addon `Lightning Nightly Updater (Unofficial)`, even if this addon is stoneold. The addon is used in parallel to the normal Lightning addon. Since then TB (Version 45.5.1) seems stable.</s>
Download the newest version at https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/channel/ (Beta 51.0b2 was sufficient for me).